Frontend not updating when deployed Nextjs13 and Orchid app
I’m working with a Next.js application deployed on a shared hosting environment using the Orchid framework. The site was previously set up by someone else and it seems they deployed the frontend through a Git repository, which I do not have access to.
Current Problem:
When I make changes to the frontend and upload files to the /websites/frontend directory, the website does not reflect these changes.
Backend changes made to the /websites/admin directory are applied successfully.
Despite uploading new files, the frontend remains unchanged, indicating that the new files are not being served or recognized by the application.

How can I ensure that changes to the /websites/frontend directory are properly applied and visible on the website?
Is it possible that the hosting environment is using a different method for serving frontend files, such as a Git repository or another caching mechanism? How to check it?

What We’ve Tried:

Local Build: Built the application locally using Node.js 16 and uploaded the .next directory to the production server, but the site did not update.
Cache Clearing: Attempted to clear browser cache and, if applicable, CDN cache, but the problem persists.
Permissions Check: Verified that permissions for uploaded files are correct.


Dont know but test with plan html files then go to Nextjs, etc

@hamidb80 could you explain it more specifically?

@Magdalena Tańska pages which are not updating are they static like Home, About etc. ?

@Beast80K This is a webstore, I was adding static changes like headings etc but also dynamic changes like displaying products and none of the changes are visible after adding the files to the server
